how to keep mac pc on when it's on file sharing?
How can I keep a Mac running when I'm using it for file sharing? It's my parents' Mac, and I use it as an external drive. When they come home, I usually close the lid, but that causes file sharing to stop. I've tried adjusting the settings, like turning off screen timeout and using a screensaver (which works but is noticeable). Any ideas?

The problem is that you're closing the laptop. MacBooks can be kept running while closed (this is sometimes known as "closed-clamshell operation"), but it requires that the MacBook be hooked up to an external display, keyboard, and mouse.

Try installing a third party application like Amphetamine, and setting it to run indefinitely.

whats amphetamine?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Change the settings on the laptop to not shut off the laptop when the top is closed by going to System Settings > Lock Screen and change the "Turn display off on power adapter when inactive" option to "Never".
Source:
Because the superuser.com ai thinks this needs a source

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

The setting change you specified does not accomplish what OP is asking for.

@Spiff The OP said his laptop causes file sharing to stop when closing the lid. This can be caused by the lid closing putting the laptop into power saving mode. My answer disables that. If they they and it does not work then we go a different direction. It is called troubleshooting.   Citation: This might help you

It isn't Ai that made that suggestion. The Community user gives feedback suggested by real community members who review new questions and answers in the various review queues.
